# How to rename R icon in Windows' XP taskbar?

Tags: windows-xp, icons, r

How to rename R icon in Windows' XP taskbar ? To display for example "R 2.13.0" instead of "RGui" ? Is it possible to do that from the inside of R (from the level of console) ?

ps. I'm not interested in building new form modified source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And more interesting thing :

```
for(i in 1:1000) {
     setWindowTitle(title=paste(i), suffix='')
     Sys.sleep(0.5)
}
```

which gives number of iteration in taskbar, that doesn't work at RStudio, unfortunately parameter of `Sys.sleep()` must be quite big, so it's useful only for loops with long time of execution of each iteration

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the icon on your desktop or on the Programs popup (in Windows) and "Rename" should be one of the options. You are only renaming the icon, not the R executable. Doing it from within R would be very painful (if it's even possible).

Comment: So there isn't any way to change the name of RGUI main window ? .Platform$GUI gives "RGui" and there is no possibility to change that parameter (only it's name) ?

Comment: That value is used by programs to determine if graphics or API differences need to be accounted for. It is not going to change either the taskbar label in Windows (which I thought you wanted to modify) or the console header in the GUI (which now seems to be your concern.) On my Mac under OSX it returns "AQUA", and nothing ever gets displayed with that name. If I change to a virtual WinXP session, it will then return "RGui".

Comment: setWindowTitle(title='R 2.13.0', suffix='')